# GPU rendering on CSS3

Tags: css, gpu

I used to write OpenGL2.1 apps on C++. Now i am working in HTML5, because i have strong belief it going to be single UI platform.

I know that a lot of CSS3 animations/rules can be forced to GPU. But, none of them allow "user-level" computations.

I know that its not what CSS was designed for, but how can i make animation with simple math on pure CSS? I don't like idea of CPU wakeups.

As an example, simple task, easily solved by shaders with 0 CPU actions:
    [Timer on pure CSS](http://codepen.io/kindofone/pen/DkhAz)
`.`

But it has an issue: it never stops. So, am I able to apply simple conditions? Like stop when animation-stop: 'content' < attr(target)

Mainly for education purposes.

Answer (score 3):

A few ideas:

[animation-iteration-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count) (MDN) is the simplest condition I could think of.

---

You could also use [CSS Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) (aka "CSS Variables") with a bit of JS:

```
:root {
  --count: 19;
}
.selector {
  animation-iteration-count: var(--count);
}
```

Now in JS you just have to modify a single value and that new value is instantly used in many declarations.

---

With JS, you can toggle class on HTML elements and CSS rules will or won't  match depending on their selector rules.

---

**Demos:**

- [Update CSS Variables with JS](http://codepen.io/wesbos/pen/adQjoY?editors=0110)
- [Parallax 3D Button with JS controlled CSS variables](https://codepen.io/electerious/pen/rroqdL?editors=0010)

You could also see ["Conditions" for CSS Variables](http://kizu.ru/en/fun/conditions-for-css-variables/) and [CSS locks](https://fvsch.com/code/css-locks/)

But if you want to make something happen or stop, outside of hacks/trick kind of abusing CSS or with overcomplicated code, then JavaScript and DOM Events are the way to go.
You're speaking of GPU, computation, OpenGL so just in case: if you need computation intensive JS then give a try to ServiceWorkers. They can't modify the DOM but they'll run in the background crunching some numbers.

Comment: Thanks. Its more about using only GPU for animations, rather than CPU. For example i can draw snowflakes on CSS, but i can't "simulate" wind. Which is possible on classic shaders. Your advice is inspiring.